# There are more solutions to this problem?

Tags: inequality

$a, b, c, d > 0$. Prove the inequality: $\dfrac{a^2}{b}+\dfrac{b^2}{c}+\dfrac{c^2}{d}+\dfrac{d^2}{a} \geqslant a+b+c+d$

I solved this problem rapidly using AM-GM, like this:

$\dfrac{a^2}{b} +b \geqslant 2\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2}{b}b} = 2a$

Making the summation we obtain what we want.

I wonder if there are more solutions to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inequality involving AM-GM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143359/inequality-involving-am-gm) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E2%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%5E2%7D%7Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%5E2%7D%7Bd%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bd%5E2%7D%7Ba%7D%5Cgeq%20a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd%24&p=1). Its current $3$ answers provide different methods. Also, another question here asking about the same inequality is [AM-GM inequality: $\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{d} + \frac{d^2}{a} \geq a + b + c + d$](/q/2072018). ...

Comment: (cont.) There are also *relatively many* AoPS threads, e.g., [Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1607978p10032659), [One more inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1479750p8628858), [Inequality Problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1926480p13220003), [Another Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1311675p7029100), [Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1359141p7442914), [AM GM problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2232852p17067845), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Basic AM-GM problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2405538p19720651), [Inequality inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1552515p9450269), [inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1423508p8010331), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG Let $a\le b\le c\le d$.
$$a^2<b^2<c^2<d^2$$
$$\frac{1}{d}\le\frac{1}{c}\le\frac{1}{b}\le\frac{1}{a}$$
By the rearrangement inequality:
$$a^2\cdot\frac{1}{b}+b^2\cdot\frac{1}{c}+c^2\cdot\frac{1}{d}+d^2\cdot\frac{1}{a}\ge a^2\cdot\frac{1}{a}+b^2\cdot\frac{1}{b}+c^2\cdot\frac{1}{c}+d^2\cdot\frac{1}{d}=a+b+c+d$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of [Sedrakyan's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality) (also known as Titu's lemma), with $\ a_1=a,\ \ a_2=b,\ \ a_3=c,\ \ a_4=d,\ \ b_1=b,\ \ b_2 = c,\ \ b_3 = d,\ \ b_4 = a.$